# InputFormatters and Onchanged functions not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter I have created a Custom Keyboard used by multiple TextFormFields to enter Digits.

Custom Keyboard has a TextEditingCOntroller named `_activeController`

late TextEditingController _activeController;

TextFormFields have their own TextEditingControllers

TextEditingController oneController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController twoController = TextEditingController();

When a TextFormField is tapped it changes to the following state by this function

```
TextField(
      onTap: () {
        //change the active controller when the textfield is tapped on (focused)
        _activeController = oneController;
      },
    ),
```

I have written the following InputFormatters to the above `TextFormField`

inputFormatters: [
FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4),
CardMonthInputFormatter(),
],

But when I type data with my Custom Keyboard, it neglects the inputFormatters. Also, the `onChanged:` function returns no result for the same scenario.

How to solve this?

P.S: Using the default keyboard with `keyboardType: TextInputType.number,` is not a solution.